# How do you keep your household pet/s away from your toy collections?

Tags: dogs, training

I own a small companion, a mixed Pomeranian and Lhasa Apso breed. Don't let his size fool you, that little bugger can be ferocious at times, chewed off the head of my beloved Snake Eyes (G.I. Joe) action figure. I learned my lesson and was wondering if you guys can recommend anything? I was looking online and found a few [wood pet gates](http://www.petstreetmall.com/Wood-Pet-Gates/3256.html). They seem like they would be able to keep him away from the living room (where I usually keep my collection). What do you guys think? And how do  you keep your pets away from your action figures?

[image]

Comment: take a look here https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18328/cat-in-a-electronics-hobbyist-house

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best way would be training. Those are your toys and yours alone. For the time being, a gate won't hurt (assuming the dog can't squeeze through or jump over it). Also depending on the age of the dog the urge to chew on things might disappear later on its own.

Other than that always remember: **Now you know, and knowing it's half the battle.** SCNR :)